# Prove Set is a Subspace of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I would like to solve the following problem:

Asume $A$ and $B$ are two subspaces from vectorial real space of matrices $m*n$ where

$A$= {$\begin{pmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$,$b=a+c;a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R} $},

$B$= {$\begin{pmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$,$c=a+2b;a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R} $},

Prove that set $A\cap B$ is a vectorial subspace of matrices $m*n$

I'm not sure if this is the right approach but I would start off by finding $A\cap B$ which I know would result in:

$A\cap B$=$\begin{pmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

Altough I'm not sure what to do with the expressions: $b=a+c$ and $c=a+2b$

After that just prove if the subset:

1. Is closed under addition.
2. Is closed under scalar multiplication.
3. Has vector $0$

Answer (score 1):

You have all the pieces.

For the intersection, *both* $b=a+c$ and $c=a+2b$ must hold. After some rearranging you have $b=-2a$ and $c=-3a$. So you can write
$$A \cap B = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&-2a&-3a\\d&0&0\end{bmatrix} : a,d \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the theorem that says "Let $U$ and $W$ be subespaces of $V$. Then, $U\cap W$ is a subespace of $V$". Both have the zero vector, because the zero vector is in $U$ and $W$. Take two elements $a, b$ in the intersection, then, $a,b\in U$ and $a,b\in W$, and like $U$ and $W$ are subespaces, $a+b\in U$ and $a+b\in W$, then, $a+b\in U\cap W$. For the scalar closure, let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a$ in the intersection, then, $a\in U$ and $a\in W$ and how $U$ and $W$ are subspaces,$\lambda a\in U$ and $\lambda a\in W$, then, $\lambda a\in U\cap W$. Your problem follows of this theorem.